# Rotating polygons to follow the curve (line) in 90 degree in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation, rotate

I have created points on the line with 60m distance. Then I've made square buffers to these points. But they all stand straight. Is it possible somehow to rotate them so they follow the line curves? Like so they all be 90 degrees to the segment of the line?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Create the line (if not already done)
2. Use the algorithm ["Points along geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) to create your points. This algorithm will automatically add a field called "angle" to the points. If you create the points another way, you can still calculate this field yourself. For example by using this expression:

   ```
   line_interpolate_angle(
       array_first(overlay_nearest('Line', $geometry)),
       line_locate_point(array_first(overlay_nearest('Line', $geometry)), $geometry)
       )
   ```
3. Run the ["Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds) algorithm, choose your input, type and size.
4. Click the box right to rotation and add a datadefined override. Use your angle field of the points (or an expression containing the angle)

[image]

Run it and done:

[image]

Comment: For Rotation in the "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" algorithm, one can use the expression directly there, no need to create an additional field

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! In my version of QGIS this tool looks a bit different, but I made it just as I wanted

Answer (score 9):

If you start with the only blue line and don't want to add new layers :

Set up the points and squares at a specific distance by adding two symbols lines (one for each).
[image]

On the square line, make sure you check *Rotate the symbol to follow the direction of the line*. [image]

The squares should now rotate along the line. If you want to change the angle, you can do it on the symbol panel (where you choose your symbol).

[image]